# How can I run one-off dyno inside another one-off dyno on Heroku using custom django-admin commands?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, heroku

I need to create one-off dyno in Django application deployed on Heroku using custom django-admin commands. I want to use Heroku Scheduler to run command `heroku run python manage.py test_function2`. It creates one-off dyno with running function `test_function2` in it. Then I would like to use `test_function2` function to create more one-off dynos. I added example code below. My problem is associated with line `command = 'heroku run:detached myworker2'` When I use `command = 'heroku run:detached myworker2'` in `test_function2` I get error `sh: 1: heroku: not found`. 
In Heroku documentation there is written [One-off dynos are created using heroku run.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#an-example-one-off-dyno) Does anyone have an idea how can I create heroku one-off dyno when I am already in one?

test_function2:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
        def handle(self, *args, **options):

            command = 'heroku run:detached myworker2'

            os.system(command)
```

Procfile:

```
web: sh -c 'gunicorn backend.wsgi --log-file -'
myworker2: python manage.py test_function2
myworker2: python manage.py test_function
```

Comment: that's unrelated to django-rest-framework :(

Comment: @Linovia I changed tags. Do you know how can I solve my problem?

Comment: Thanks. I would have left an answer if I knew.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What are you actually trying to _accomplish_ by doing this?

Comment: @Chris https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47971506/how-can-i-run-function-asynchronously-to-make-calculation-parallelly-on-heroku-w I wouldn't create 500 schedulers manually but I would create automatically 500 one-off dyno workers (function test_function) to calculate results. Do you know solution?